# Ways to prove that the closed interval 0;1 with the absolute value is compact.

Tags: functional-analysis

I am looking for a way to prove this without using Heine-Borel. I want to use the definition of compactness: From any covering of E by open sets we can extract a finite union of open sets that still covers E. Is it possible?

Thank you.

Comment: You'll basically end up proving Heine-Borel in doing so.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. See Theorem 4.39 https://books.google.it/books?id=89zyCQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=it&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Given an open cover of $[0,1]$ consider $F=\{x\in [0,1]: [0,x]$ is finitly covered$\}$. Then prove that $\sup F =\max F =1$.

Answer (score 2):

I want to show this proof.

Let $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{A})$ be a topological space where $\mathcal{A}$ is the euclidean topology: $\mathcal{A}=\{Y \subseteq \mathbb{R}: Y \ \text{is union of open intervals of the type $(a,b)$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$}\}$.

Let $\sigma$ be an open cover of the set $[0,1]$, for this reason $[0,1] \subseteq \bigcup_{H \in \sigma}{H}$. Now let's consider the following set:
$$
X=\biggl\{x \in [0,1]: \exists\,\gamma \subseteq \sigma \ \text{finite}:  [0,x]\subseteq \bigcup_{H \in \gamma}{H}\biggr\}.
$$

The set $X$ is not empty: $0 \in [0,1] \subseteq \bigcup_{H \in \sigma}{H} $, so there exists $H \in \sigma$ such that $0 \in H$ and this means that $0 \in X$. Let notice that $1$ is an upper bound of $X$, consequentially $X$ admits supremum, let be $z=\text{sup}\,{X}$. Furthemore since $1$ is an upper bound of $X$ then $z \in [0,1]$, thus exists $A \in \sigma$ such that $z \in A$.
The set $A$ is open, this ensures the existence of $\varepsilon>0$ such that $z-\varepsilon>0$ and $(z-\varepsilon,z+\varepsilon) \subseteq A$. Since $z \in \overline{X}$, there exists $x \in (z-\varepsilon,z+\varepsilon)\cap X$ and noticing that $x \in X$, there exists a finite sub-cover $\gamma$ of $[0,x]$ extracted by $\sigma$, in particular there exists also a finite sub-cover of $[0,x]\cup (z-\varepsilon,z+\varepsilon)=[0,z+\varepsilon]$ extracted by $\sigma$, this finite sub-cover is $\gamma \cup \{A\}$. This highlights that $[0,z+\varepsilon]\cap [0,1] \subseteq X$, in particular $z \in X$, i.e $z=\text{max}\,X$.

Suppose to the contrary that $z=\text{max}\,X<1$, then there exists $k \in [0,1]$ such that $z<k<z+\varepsilon$ (this is simply true both when $z+\varepsilon\le 1$ as well as when $z+\varepsilon>1$). This also means that $k \in [0,1] \cap [0,z+\varepsilon]$, i.e $k \in X$, but it's a contradiction because it would imply that $k \le z=\text{max}\,X$.

The conclusion is that $z=1$, consequentially  $[0,1]$ admits a finite sub-cover extracted by $\sigma$ and it is compact by definition.